# MS SQL To Informix 11 - Group By converted datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by, informix

I am attempting to move a stored procedure from Microsoft SQL Server 2000 to Informix 11. The original SP contains a final select statement with a GROUP BY statement that includes a converted datetime:

```
group by convert(varchar(8), c.startDateTime, 1)
```

When I convert this to Informix syntax I get a syntax error at run time:

```
GROUP BY (c.startDateTime::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY)::VARCHAR(10)
```

Can anyone please point me to how, if possible, this can be done in Informix?  If this is not possible, which I suspect, how would you typically handle this in the overall query?

Comment: What is the syntax error? Some DBMS do not allow `GROUP BY function()` or anything else bu only `GROUP BY column`. Test and if that's causing the error, wrap the query and the function inside a subquery and do the grouping in the external.

Comment: I am using Server Studio 8.5 to debug and the error i get is just "syntax error".  The overall query that this is part of is about 150 lines and there are many other fields in the Group By, but this is the only one throwing an error. Not sure if that is helpful but it would be very hard to wrap the query and then group the results.

Comment: See my other suggestion/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to convert from this:

```
SELECT a, b, c 

FROM  ...

GROUP BY (c.startDateTime::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY)::VARCHAR(10) ;
```

to something like:

```
SELECT a, b, c, 
    (c.startDateTime::DATETIME YEAR TO DAY)::VARCHAR(10) AS d

FROM  ...

GROUP BY 4 ;        --- meaning: the 4th column in the SELECT clause
```

Comment: This is also what I'd recommend. The ordinal position syntax `GROUP BY 1, 2 ..` lets you get away with pretty much anything.

Answer (score 1):

In Informix, it is generally not required to convert datetime fields to character strings to manipulate them. Instead, use the extend function.

Example, if `c.StartDateTime` is defined as a datetime year to second e.g. 2012-10-28 23:00:00 and you want just the date portion, use extend (`c.StartDateTime`, year to day). This will return 2012-10-28.

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting to Informix syntax for dates to varchar in mm/dd/yyyy (mssql style=1) as

```
TO_CHAR(c.StartDateTime,"%m/%d/%iY")
```

???